# Minimum memory for RAR decompression

Tags: iphone, android, memory, blackberry, rar

What's the minimum memory needed to run a RAR decompression algorithm?

I want to port a RAR decompression algorithm to mobiles (iPhone, Android and BlackBerry) and want to know if there's a bare minimum of memory needed before starting. I've heard that RAR decompression requires much more memory than ZIP decompression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a lot. The maximum size of the dictionary are [4 MB](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/rar/trunk/technote.txt?revision=298704&view=markup&sortby=date#l173), but at least the official unrar library (which is built from the same source as WinRAR) [takes over 24 MB](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/rar/trunk/unrar/suballoc.cpp?revision=290883&view=markup&sortby=date#l89) in some decompression algorithms.

(as to the last statement: note that the `t` is at least 1 MB (`uint t=SASize << 20;`), but can be more because [SASize may be more than 1](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/rar/trunk/unrar/model.cpp?revision=290883&view=markup&sortby=date#l564))

Comment: Thanks Artefacto, this is what I what looking for. Can you provide some links/references to accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Can't give you a concrete number, but I remember using WinRAR back in 2001 on my PocketPC with only 64mb of RAM, about half of which was shared for storage -- so I'm pretty sure a modern phone should suffice.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure. If I'm not mistaken, Android devices have only 16MB or 24MB for applications.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of Comic Viewers on the iPhone that support .cbr so I its doable.

Comment: I know, but that doesn't answer the question. If possible I want to make a multi-platform RAR decompression algorithm, and iPhone is only one of the target platforms.

Comment: @hgpc - What, then, are the minimum system specs for the least capable device you would like this to run on?  Without solid specifications, it's very difficult to provide a definitive answer.

Comment: I would like to know the minimum memory requirements of a RAR decompression algorithm, which don't depend of the target specs. But to answer your question, let's assume that I have 8MB of RAM and 128MB of external storage for this.